# Breadth First Search Pruning and Memory Leak C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I'm doing a project that requires me to solve a maze where you cannot turn left.  The program is working fine, except for in cases with very large input.

My general strategy was to make each spot in the maze 4 nodes in the graph, corresponding to UP, DOWN, LEFT, and RIGHT, where each node has an edge going straight and right, and where straight has weight 0 and right has weight 1.  Edges are represented as an object in my code, and has a pointer to is destination node and its originating node.

To find an optimal path (the path with fewest right turns), I used a breadth-first search with a double ended queue.  I use the deque to be able to push weight 1 nodes to the back and weight 0 nodes to the front.  However, I allocate a small amount memory during the search and not cleaning it up anywhere, which is presumably causing my program to fail very large maze inputs.

Here is the code (specifically the for loop that checks adjacent edges of a node within the BFS):

```
    //t is a node object in the graph that has been popped out of the deque

    //loop that checks each adjacent node from t (adj is a vector of edges)
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < t.adj.size(); i++)
    {
        if(!t.adj[i].used)
        {
            if(!t.adj[i].dest->visited)
            {
                //Memory leak location
                t.adj[i].dest->prev = new node(t);

                t.adj[i].used = true;

                //weight of an edge is 1 if it's a right turn, 0 otherwise
                if(t.adj[i].weight == 1) 
                {
                    //put the heavier nodes on the end of the queue
                    nodes.push_back(t.adj[i].dest);
                }
                //0-weight nodes on the top
                else nodes.push_front(t.adj[i].dest);                
            }

        }
```

I've been trying to figure out how to better prune the search and how to free up this allocation when I definitely won't need those nodes anymore.  But I need some direction for how to think about this.  Let me know if additional code is needed.

Thanks.

EDIT: Node and edge classes (excuse my disregard for standard class designing principles, just threw them together quickly):

```
class node
{
public:
    node();
    node(Direction d, int r, int c, NodeType t);
    ~node(); //empty definition
    node(const node* n);
    node(const node& n);
    node& operator=(const node& n);
    node& operator=(const node* n);

    void addAdj(node* a, int w);
    void printAdj() const;
    string direction() const;

    void print() const;
    bool operator<(const node& n) const;


    int distance; //from start
    bool visited;
    node* prev;
    vector<Edge> adj;
    Direction dir;
    int row, col;
    NodeType type;
};
///////////////////////
struct Edge
{

    Edge();
    Edge(node* o, node* d, int c);

    node* org;
    node* dest;
    int weight;
    bool used;
```

};

Answer (score 1):

What if `node` takes a pointer to `t` (so you don't need the full defintion of `t`'s type (`node`?) for `node::adj[]::dest::prev`'s declaration and take `node` by value (instead of allocating it dynamically) for `t.adj[i].dest->prev`?

This would ensure that you do not leak memory as you are not allocating anything dynamically.  The drawback is you need to ensure there is no reference to `t` via `dest::prev` once `t` is out of scope.

In this case you would change the line

```
t.adj[i].dest->prev = new node(t);
```

to

```
t.adj[i].dest->prev = node(&t);
```

You will need a special value to denote invalid `prev` (what was NULL before).  Perhaps use `node(NULL)`?

Alternative: use a shared pointer (BOOST provides a selection if you are not using C++11) to ensure automatic deallocation when all references are gone.  You will have to make sure you don't keep circular references around forever, preventing the deallocation of "zombi" nodes (nodes that will not be used again, but cannot be deallocated as there are still references to them

Comment: My brain isn't fully comprehending what you're trying to say here, could you try to explain again? (I've been coding for several hours, so my brain is turning to mush)

EDIT: Sadly I cannot use boost or C++11, as this is a class project where those things are restricted.

Comment: You can roll your own shared pointer implementation, although that approach certainly has a high probability for error (a [pointer for reading](http://ootips.org/yonat/4dev/smart-pointers.html) on the general idea) -- see edit for some additional clarification for the first idea.  I cannot give you more as I do not know your structures/classes

Comment: When I use that line of code I get the following error: "cannot convert ‘node’ to ‘node*’ in assignment".  I will put my node and edge classes in the original post, one moment.

Comment: Yes, you will need to redesing your structs/classes to allow that syntax

Comment: Do I just need another constructor of some type? I've never seen this syntax so I'm a bit confused by it.

Comment: OK, so you are copy-constructing a node in the dynamic allocation.  Try just assigning `&t`: `t.adj[i].dest->prev = &t;` -- the same consideration about reference validity holds

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10147/discussion-between-attila-and-slims)

Comment: I've tried to do that too but I get memory errors.  Pretty sure because when the outer loop starts again it assigns t to something else, which changes t.adj[i].dest->prev